# Using a subquery in a case statement in a where clause

Tags: sql, subquery, case, where-clause

I want to select different results (from a temp table) based on what a certain parameter is set to in the query.  I want to exclude certain inventory SKUs if a particular warehouse is selected. I am getting this error, unfortunately.

**Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 310
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.**

Here is a simplified temp table I am selecting from for example...

| InvtID |
| --- |
| C-123 |
| C-789 |
| C-20042 |
| 12345 |
| 56789 |
| 35353 |

```
declare @siteid VARCHAR(10) = 'CF'

select *
from #temptable
where InvtID in (Case when @siteid='CF' then (
                                                select I.InvtID
                                                from dbo.Inventory I
                                                where I.InvtID not like 'C-%'
                                                union all
                                                select 'C-20042')
                        else (select I.InvtID from dbo.Inventory I) end)
```

expected result

| InvtID |
| --- |
| C-20042 |
| 12345 |
| 56789 |
| 35353 |

Is there a better way to accomplish my task, or is there a way to fix my current attempted solution?

Comment: Skip the case _expression_, use regular AND/OR instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select *
from #temptable FT
where (@siteid='CF' and (FT.InvtID not like 'C-%' or FT.InvtID='C-20042'))
or @siteid<>'CF'
```